# Can't switch to 3d view in game mode in Unity 3d

Tags: unity, scene2d

When I create a new project in Unity 3d 2017.3, I set the development mode to 3d. Let's take an example now. I create a 3d cube object (everything fine till now)  and then click the play button.
As soon as I start playing the game, the view changes to 2d. All I see is a square in front of me at the horizon i.e. the view is 2d and from a different perspective instead of from the main camera's perspective.
I went to Edit>Project Settings>Editor menu and set the default behaviour to 3d (It was already 3d). Unfortunately it didn't work. Any Suggestions?

Comment: The editor 2D/3D toggle doesn't change anything upon entering play mode. All it does is set some defaults when creating a new scene or importing a new image. Can you show us a screenshot of your editor before and after hitting the Play button? Ideally, select your Main Camera and disable the game window's "Maximize on Play" setting, so we can see it highlighted in the scene view and see its transform properties in the Inspector.

Answer (score 1):

Your viewpoint in your editor is not your camera's view. I'm working on a 2D game, but routinely view it from a 3D perspective while working on it, because it makes it convenient for stacking objects in z space (if I don't want to use layers).

Anyway, my point is that your game view is going to come from your camera, not the editor interface. It's unlike like some 3D apps, where you are always "looking through" a camera while you work. Try clicking on your camera and see what it's view looks like (you should get a "camera view" window). Also, while in the editor, zoom out and select your camera gizmo in the editor view and try adjusting it's position and/or rotation to get the angle you want in your camera view.

If you can't find your camera in your editor view, make sure your camera isn't accidentally on Orthographic, which will give you an infinitely parallel frustum, and may not be easily accessible from the editor view.